# How do I pass Django local variable of a funtion in views to javascript fetch API?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am all new to javascript. I am making a like button that will increase the number of likes of a post asynchronously without reloading the whole page. Following is my Django views function.

> views.py

```
@login_required
def likepost(request,id):
    post = NewPost.objects.get(id = id)
    is_like = False
    for like in post.likepost.all():
        if like == request.user and request.method == "POST":
            is_like = True
            break
    
    if not is_like:
        post.likepost.add(request.user)
    
    else:
        post.likepost.remove(request.user)
    
    return JsonResponse({
        "id" : id,
        "is_like" : is_like,
        "num_like" : post.likepost.count()
    })
```

Here `id` is the primary key of NewPost model. My javascript will fetch an API using this `id` variable. Here is my js function.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.querySelector('#like').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function());
})


function like_function(){
    fetch(`index/${id}/like`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Like";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Unlike";
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="like_function()" id = "like" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </button>
    <small id="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
    {% block script %} 
        <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Comment</button>
    <a href="{% url 'postpage' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">View Post</a>
```

Here, I've shared my javascript function as well as my HTML template.
If I click the like button following message appears.
[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: There is no `id` in the code. Can you point from where the value of `id` will be calculated ?

Comment: The problem is that you are not passing id to your js function, you can pass it on click function like `button onclick="like_function(this.value)" value="your id here"` and catch in the function `function like_function(id)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the item primary key in the `like_function` call:

```
<button onclick="like_function({{ posts.pk }})" id = "like" class="btn btn-link"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> </button>
```

then you define the `like_function` as:

```
function like_function(id) {
    fetch(`index/${id}/like`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Like";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Unlike";
        }
    })
}
```